# iframe content doesn't fit

Tags: css, iframe

I have a situation, that I have a `iframe` which I can't manipulate in its height. I mean the `iframe` has a fixed height of `1000px` and I'm not allowed the change it. So what I'm trying to do is to make the content fit in the `iframe` somehow. How can I archive this? I'm totally new in CSS. Thanks!

```
<iframe style="height:1000px" src="http://www.w3schools.com">
    <div class="content"> 
       <div class="redDot"></div>
    </div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the content dynamic? What are you trying to achieve? Will allowing the iframe to scroll suffice?

Comment: no content is not dynamic. just i need to fit my content in iframe.. I implemented my content and when i tried i saw that my content is being cut.. So i want to know if is there a way fitting my content without touching iframe

Comment: Well, how about setting the content's height to 999px?

Comment: tried but didnt work..My content is bigger than iframe 's size

Comment: Please provide the CSS and HTML of the parent page. Even though you can't alter it,  it's CSS and HTML is the biggest factor, so it's probably helpful to know. BTW, you shouldn't stuff elements between the iframe's tags. I know it seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: You cannot insert html into an iframe tag, it only loads the page linked. Your div .content might be shown if the browsers doesn't know how to deal with iframe .. but is there any nowdays ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html,body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
      overflow: hidden;

    }
    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the `style="height:1000px" ` that must be there?

Comment: I think it's not a must !

Comment: It is, as in the question is says: _I mean the iframe has a fixed height of 1000px and I'm not allowed the change it._